# VSCode terminal ctrl-click in out of source build does not find file

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, visual-studio-code

So, I've got a project directory laid out like so:

```
.vscode/
build/
src/
```

When I do an out-of-source build, all my compiler warnings & errors point to files with paths like `../src/stuff.cpp:123:4`, with a leading `../` because GCC is running from the `build` folder.

Then when I ctrl-click on that in VSCode, it's confused:
[image: ../src/stuff.cpp:123 No matching results]

I need to manually delete `../` every time, for VSCode to find the file.

Is there a VSCode setting I can tweak for that ?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following parts in the task

```json
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build"
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "base": "$gcc",
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^../(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
          "file": 1,
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "severity": 4,
          "message": 5
        }
      },
```

Now the errors are clickable in the PROBLEMS panel